# Reality Question : Do you tune the IIS Max thread pool?

Tags: multithreading, iis, load-balancing, scaling, worker

By default, the IIS 6.0 process creates as many as four threads per processor. We can adjust the maximum number of threads in the IIS 6.0 service process by adding the MaxPoolThreads entry to the following registry path:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Inetinfo\Parameters and give the value between 2 - 20.

- I would like to know in reality, are these changes done in the Servers to tune the IIS ??
- What's the calculation behind deciding the Web Server count in a Web farm environment (LOAD / SPEED...)?
- What are the best practices followed to configure the Load Balancing??
- On what basis we do the Horizontal Scaling / Vertical Scaling?

Comment: Question better asked at ServerFault?

Comment: thx..will move this question to Server Fault :)